# MongoDB C# driver fails to reconnect after stepDown

Tags: mongodb, c#, aws

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment in AWS that constantly verifies the DB is accessible by querying the mongos for one document. We only speak to the DB routers and not to specific instances.

During a stepDown, half the servers are immediately declared as unhealthy, whereas the other half, which uses the same connection string, works fine.

We use the official MongoDB C# driver v.1.10 (Mongo 2.6.1) and I have a feeling the driver doesn't recognize the re-election process but latches to the one node he got a hold of.

Is this a known phenomenon? What are the ways to bypass it?

Edit:
The connection string uses routers and no options, as follows:
mongodb://user:password@company.routerA.mongohost.com:9999,company.routerB.mongohost.com:9999,company.routerC.mongohost.com:9999/DatabaseName (names and ports altered)

Comment: Assuming you have the correct [connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/), the expected behaviour is that the driver will automatically discover any changes in your deployment as a result of elections or replica set / sharding configuration. There will be a brief window of exceptions raised for situations where a primary is currently unavailable, but writes will switch to a newly elected primary. Can you include an example of your connection string?